# How to replace all the numbers without am or pm to a standard string?

Tags: r, str-replace, gsub, stringr

I have a vector like below :

```
x <- c('3b  and to 10 am ','1c  and to 12 pm','#01-93  and to 10 am ')
```

I need to replace all the numbers without string am or pm to "none" .So I tried using

```
sub('.*-([0-9]+).*' ,'none',x)
```

But this does not works.
My expected output is like below:

```
x <- c('none  and to 10 am ','none and to 12 pm','none  and to 10 am ')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex with a lookahead to check for am or pm. I used the stringr package, but it should work with base functions as well.

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(x, "(\\S*[0-9]+\\S*)(?!\\S*\\s(am|pm))", "none")

# > "none  and to 10 am " "none  and to 12 pm"  "none  and to 10 am "
```

If there could be multiple numbers to replace in each element, use `str_replace_all()` instead of `str_replace()`

If you then want to get rid of excess spaces, I recommend using `stringr::str_squish()`.

---

**Regex breakdown**

- `\\S*` looks for zero or more non white space characters.
- `[0-9]` matches the numers 0 - 9.
- So `(\\S*[0-9]+\\S*)` looks for a number with zero or more non-white space characters on either side. This matches all of the cases in your example, though you may have to be more specific if this assumption is incorrect.
- `\\s` matches a white space character
- `(am|pm)` matches am or pm
- `(?!x)` looks ahead and discounts any matches which are followed by an x
- So `(?!\\S*\\s(am|pm))` looks ahead and discounts any matches which have an am or pm after the next space. This is crucial in discounting the second number.

Comment: Thanks man for the breakdown .But I am just curious of this scenario `x <- c('give 45 cents for 1 product on 25/9 between 11 am ')` .It doesn't seems to work.Any reason why ? is it because of the "/"  `x <- c('give 45 cents for 1 product on 25  between 11 am ')` also doesn't seem to work

Comment: The problem is that `str_replace()` only looks for the first match and then it moves on to the next element - these examples have more than one match. Use `str_replace_all()` instead and it should work.

Comment: Oh I see forget about the `str_replace_all()` function

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lookahead `?!` operator to not match am and pm. It is important that you set perl to true as otherwise, the expression is not valid.

```
sub('#?[0-9]+(\\-[0-9]+)?[a-z]*(?!am|pm)' , 'none', x, perl = TRUE)
```